# Display first 50 characters only in php,mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two fields in database table, title and description. I am displaying tha data in php while loop.

My Code :

```
$sql = "select * from sightseeing";
    $i = 1;
    $res = mysql_query($sql, $conn); 
    if( mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
       {

        echo "<tr>
          <td>".$i++."</td>
          <td>".$row["title"]."</td>
          <td>".$row["description"]."</td>
        </tr>";
      }
   }
```

I want to show only first 50 characters from description field. How to do that?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: substr($row['description'], 0, 50);
See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
 $sql = "select * from sightseeing";
$i = 1;
$res = mysql_query($sql, $conn); 
if( mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{

echo "<tr>
  <td>".$i++."</td>
  <td>".$row["title"]."</td>
  <td>".substr($row['description'], 0, 50)."</td>
 </tr>";
  }
  }
```

Comment: you are welcome, could you please tick my answer as accepted

Answer (score 1):

use MySQL `LEFT`

```
select *,LEFT(description , 50) description from sightseeing
```